# Installing hyperledger fabric peers on virtual machine

Tags: blockchain

I want deploy each peer of hyper ledger fabric on different virtual machines.Suppose consider two machine each has two VMs..so total 4 VMs on two machines..So I want to deploy 4 Hyper ledger fabric peer on this 4 VMs?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you want to do?Do you want to know the process for doing that?

Comment: yeah I want to know  the process?

Comment: I am not getting one thing...you can run your peer nodes (including the endorsing peers) in a docker container...what special purpose does running in VM gives...if you give me a significant reason i can try that out...i guess not many have done that given the mobility that docker provides

Answer (score 0):

Keep configtx.yaml and crypto-config.yaml without any change.

You have to divide docker-compose file and prepare on for each virtual machine.

- First vm will have Orderer, CA and  Peer0 + Couchdb0
- Second will have Peer1 + Couchdb1
- Third will have Peer2 + Couchdb2
- Fourth will have Peer3 + Couchdb3

Then You have to configure Docker networking ( Overlay or adding extra_hosts ).

1st VM Extra hosts :

```
extra_hosts:
- "peer1.org1.example.com:<2nd machine IP address>"
- "peer2.org1.example.com:<3ed machine IP address>"
- "peer3.org1.example.com:<4th machine IP address>"
```

2nd VM Extra Hosts :

```
extra_hosts:
- "orderer.example.com:<First machine IP address>"
- "peer0.org1.example.com:<First machine IP address>"
- "ca.example.com:<First machine IP address>"
- "peer0.org1.example.com:<First machine IP address>"
- "peer2.org1.example.com:<3ed machine IP address>"
- "peer3.org1.example.com:<4th machine IP address>"
```

etc for remaining VM's ..

Then You have to start all containers in the first machine and creating a channel by the below script.

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
```

And Join channel by the below script :

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

Then you have to start docker containers in all other machines and join created channel by this code:

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp" peer0.org2.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

Please visit the below link for full tutorial.

[Setup Hyperledger Fabric in multiple physical machines](https://medium.com/1950labs/setup-hyperledger-fabric-in-multiple-physical-machines-d8f3710ed9b4)